# how to read a php array from php file in python

Tags: python

lets say we want to make a python config reader from php.

config.php

```
$arr = array(
    'a config',
    'b config',
    'c config => 'with values'
)

$arr2 = array(
    'a config',
    'b config',
    'c config => 'with values'
)
```

readconfig.py

```
f = open('config.php', 'r')
// somehow get the array then turns it into pythons arr1 and arr2

print arr1
# arr1 = {'a config', 'b config', 'c config': 'with values'}

print arr2
# arr2 = {'a config', 'b config', 'c config': 'with values'}
```

is this possible in python ?

Comment: use ini or json or yaml or xml

Comment: If you write a parser for the PHP array syntax then it is possible. I'd highly suggest you to use a portable format such as YAML or even a file with plain `key=value` lines.

Answer (score 8):

```
from subprocess import check_output
import json

config = check_output(['php', '-r', 'echo json_encode(include "config.php");'])
config = json.loads(config)
```

where `config.php` returns an array:

```
return [
    'param1' => 'value1',
    'param2' => 'value2',
];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse config usin PHP script
2. Save config vars to a file using JSON
3. Execute parser from Pytson using os.system()
4. Read JSON file in Python

Comment: i still don`t get the 2. and 3. can you explain it more ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a variation of Eugenes:

In my situation the php file only set variables, it did not return an array.

Thus, I had to perform the include before the json_encode; then, encode particular variables.  This was for reading version.php for ownCloud. See https://github.com/owncloud/core

E.g.

```
vFileName=configDict['ocDir']+'/version.php'
cmd=['/usr/bin/php','-r','include "'+vFileName+'"; echo json_encode(array($OC_Version,$OC_VersionString));']
ocVersion, ocVersionString=json.loads(subprocess.check_output(cmd))
```